# How can I attach new columns in a .txt file based on the value of a specific column using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make the following program and I am not able to do it. I have a .txt file with 4 columns (X, Y, Wave and Intensity). X and Y are coordinates and I don't care about them, but Wave is a column of values which are increasing up to a maximum and then start again. I need that every time this loop is repeated, the Intensity data are attached to a new adjacent column, so that I can represent all the spectra. The data I have looks like this:

[My .txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8g0Q.png)

I want to have the first column for the wavenumber and the following columns for all intensities. Each column should correspond to the intensities corresponding to each cycle. Like:

Wave    Sample 1     Sample 2    Sample 3...

I tried this with the help of ChatGPT but did not worked

def procesar_archivo(archivo_entrada, archivo_salida):
# Abrir el archivo de entrada
with open(archivo_entrada, 'r') as entrada:
lineas = entrada.readlines()

```
# Crear listas vacías para almacenar los datos procesados
nuevos_datos = []
nueva_linea = []

# Iterar sobre las líneas del archivo de entrada
for linea in lineas:
    valores = linea.strip().split('\t')  # Suponiendo que las columnas están separadas por tabulaciones

    # Verificar si el valor de #X ha cambiado
    if nueva_linea and nueva_linea[0] != valores[0]:
        nuevos_datos.append(nueva_linea)  # Agregar la línea procesada a los nuevos datos
        nueva_linea = []  # Reiniciar la línea para los siguientes datos

    nueva_linea.extend(valores[1:5])  # Agregar los datos de las 4 columnas siguientes

nuevos_datos.append(nueva_linea)  # Agregar la última línea procesada

# Escribir los nuevos datos en el archivo de salida
with open(archivo_salida, 'w') as salida:
    for linea in nuevos_datos:
        salida.write('\t'.join(linea) + '\n')

print("Procesamiento completado.")
```